# Android Thread modify EditText

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-edittext

I am having a problem with modifying EditText in another function started by the thread:

```
Thread thRead = new Thread( new Runnable(){
    public void run(){
       EditText _txtArea = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtArea);
       startReading(_txtArea);
    }
 });
```

my function is as follows:

```
public void startReading(EditText _txtArea){
         _txtArea.setText("Changed");
}
```

It always force closes while trying to modify the edittext. Does someone know why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

UI views should not be modified from non-UI thread. The only thread that can touch UI views is the "main" or "UI" thread, the one that calls `onCreate()`, `onStop()` and other similar component lifecycle function.

So, whenever your application tries to modify UI Views from non-UI thread, Android throws an early exception to warn you that this is not allowed. That's because UI is not thread-safe, and such an early warning is actually a great feature.

---

**UPDATE:**

You can use `Activity.runOnUiThread()` to update UI. Or use `AsyncTask`. But since in your case you need to continuously read data from Bluetooth, `AsyncTask` should not be used.

Here is an example for `runOnUiThread()`:

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {            
    @Override
    public void run() {
        //this will run on UI thread, so its safe to modify UI views.
         _txtArea.setText("Changed");
    }
});
```

Comment: i see that makes sense. My issue is that i am writing a program that continousley reads from the bluetooth and prints the data obtained from the buffer onto an edittext box. The continous reading is done in a thread. Do you have any suggestions as to how i can output the results?

Comment: Thanks for the help. How would i write that code to work with mine? Sorry i'm new to threading... 

Thread thRead = new runOnUiThread(new Runnable() { etc... would that work?

Comment: Is it true that `runOnUiThread` is more performant than asynctask?

Answer (score 4):

First of all take a look at your log, it usually contains a stack trace when an app shuts down.

You shouldn't run the thread like you normally do, instead use `runOnUiThread`:

```
Runnable thRead = new Runnable(){
   public void run() {
      EditText _txtArea = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtArea);
      startReading(_txtArea);
   }
};
runOnUiThread(thRead);
```

The explaination: Only the UI thread is allowed to change the state of UI components.

Comment: This stopped the force close however nothing is changed on the Edittext (as in no text appears) perhaps because it is a different instance?

Comment: Should i be doing something else?

Comment: A stack trace would help. It is assumed that findViewById actually returns something useful. If you are running it with a separate component it may be null.  As you have accepted another answer, you don't need to post the stack trace ;) On another note: The Handler class is also useful for this, but threading will always be prone to concurrency errors and such.

Answer (score 1):

This article may help you.

http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/05/painless-threading.html

There are few options:
1. run it on UI thread [Activity.runOnUiThread(Runnable)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread%28java.lang.Runnable%29)
2. use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Answer (score 1):

Except `runOnUiThread()` (which works), there is also another way, which I know of:

Define a handler in your UI (Activity) class:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

.....

    Handler uiThreadHandler = new Handler() {
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            Object o = msg.obj;
            if (o==null) o = "";
            TextView textIn = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textin);
            textIn.setText(o.toString());
        }
    };

}
```

and from inside some thread you can call it:

```
Message msg = uiThreadHandler.obtainMessage();
msg.obj = "Text for EditView";
uiThreadHandler.sendMessage(msg);
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, the main thread is the UI thread. All code that modifies the appearance of the application needs to be run in this thread. If you want to have multiple threads in your application that can modify the UI I would suggest using the AsyncTask class.

```
public someMethod(){
    new ChangeTextTask().execute();
}

private class ChangeTextTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        startReading(_txtArea);
        return null;
    }
}
```

However, you need to take steps to prevent multiple threads from accessing the EditText object at once. Otherwise you'll wind up getting a CurrentModificationException error.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html