# Android TCP client read socket in a TextView

Tags: android, tcpclient

I am developing a TCPclient for Android device. 
I can connect to a server and I can track that I receive message from the server.
I would like to display the result sent by the server on the client GUI with the `TextView textview_textin`

Could you help me to do that

Thanks a lot

```
public class JssclientActivity extends Activity {
private EditText serverIp;

private Button connectPhones;

private String serverIpAddress = "192.168.0.2";

private boolean connected = false;

private TextView textview_textin;



public class ClientThread implements Runnable {

    public void run() {
        try {

            InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(serverIpAddress);
            Log.d("ClientActivity", "C: Connecting...");
            Socket socket = new Socket(serverAddr, 2600);
            connected = true;
            while (connected) {
                try {

                    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
                    String inMsg = "";
                    char buf[] = null;
                     int val = in.read();
                     while (-1 != val) {
                        inMsg = in.readLine();
                    }

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("ClientActivity", "S: Error", e);
                }
            }
            socket.close();
            Log.d("ClientActivity", "C: Closed.");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("ClientActivity", "C: Error", e);
            connected = false;
        }
    }
}


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    textview_textin = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textin);
    connectPhones = (Button) findViewById(R.id.connect);

    connectPhones.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {  
     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
         if (!connected) {
             //serverIpAddress = serverIp.getText().toString();
            if (!serverIpAddress.equals("")) {
                 Thread cThread = new Thread(new ClientThread());
                 cThread.start();
                }            
         }
     }
 });

}
}
```

---

Thanks a lot for your replies

I can connect to the device but I receive nothing. I don't know why?

Here what I tried,

```
 public class JssclientActivity extends Activity {
 private EditText serverIp;

 private Button connectPhones;

 private String serverIpAddress = "192.168.20.21";

private boolean connected = false;

 private TextView textview_textin;

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.main);

  textview_textin = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textin);
connectPhones = (Button) findViewById(R.id.connect);



ClientThread ct = new ClientThread(new ClientThread.SocketCallback() {
      public void onReceived(final String msg) {
        JssclientActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
          @Override
          public void run() {
              textview_textin.setText(msg);
          }
        });
      }
    });

  }
 }




 class ClientThread implements Runnable {

interface SocketCallback {
  void onReceived(String msg);
}
private SocketCallback callback;

private boolean connected;

private Socket socket;

public ClientThread(ClientThread.SocketCallback cb) {
      this.callback = cb;
      try {InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName("192.168.20.21");
      Log.d("ClientActivity", "C: Connecting...");
      //Socket
    socket = new Socket(serverAddr, 2600);
      connected = true;
      } catch (Exception e) {
          Log.e("ClientActivity", "C: Error", e);
          connected = false;
      }
    }

 public void run() {
      while (connected) {
          try {

              BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new        InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
              String inMsg = "";
              char buf[] = null;
               int val = in.read();
          //     while (-1 != val) {
           //       inMsg = in.readLine();
            //  }
               while (-1 != val) {
                  inMsg = in.readLine();
                  this.callback.onReceived(inMsg);
                }

          } catch (Exception e) {
              Log.e("ClientActivity", "S: Error", e);
          }
      }
    //  socket.close();
      Log.d("ClientActivity", "C: Closed.");

 }
 }
```

Please could you help me?

Thanks

Comment: You should rather edit your Question and put your Queries again, not by putting it as answer. so I suggest delete this answer and edit your main Question as User coming to this post will check Question not this so it would be better for you to get rellavent answers.

Answer (score 1):

create a callback class,

```
interface SocketCallback {
  void onReceived(String msg);
}
```

this can be an inner of `ClientThread`, as they are logically related. that's not required but it's good design.

have your `Runnable` class accept an instance of this callback in it's constructor.

```
public ClientThread(ClientThread.SocketCallback cb) {
  this.callback = cb;
}
```

when you construct your `Runnable` (`ClientThread`), do so from your UI class (`JssClientActivity`), like this,

```
ClientThread ct = new ClientThread(new ClientThread.SocketCallback() {
  public void onReceived(String msg) {
    JssClientActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        myTextView.setText(msg);
      }
    });
  }
}};
```

finally, in `ClientThread`, when you receive a message, call the callback,

```
while (-1 != val) {
  inMsg = in.readLine();
  this.callback.onReceived(inMsg);
}
```

note that you cannot update the UI from the thread where ClientThread is running. it must be updated from the UI thread, hence the call to `runOnUiThread()`.

Comment: if this answered your question, please accept it by clicking on the outline of the check mark to the left of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the text of a TextView by using the `setText()` method of it.

Example:

```
textview_textin.setText(yourText)
```

By using `runOnUiThread()` you will be able to access your TextView. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7028229/1401510).