# how to read data from object in tcp socket android

Tags: android

I am using TCP socket connection.
Server sends the data in an object and I need to receive and read it.
Server sends the data like this

```
public class SymbolData
{
public string Symbol { get; set; }
public double AskPrice { get; set; }
public double BidPrice { get; set; }
public double Open { get; set; }
public double High { get; set; }
public double Low { get; set; }
public double Close { get; set; }
public double PerChange { get; set; }
public double NetChange { get; set; }
public int Volume { get; set; }
}
```

My code is as below. I donno my flow is correct or not.

```
public class Client implements Runnable, java.io.Serializable{

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {
            Socket s = new Socket("172.16.x.xx",xxx);

            //outgoing stream redirect to socket
            BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));              
            InputStream is = new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());
            ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

            int nRead;
            byte[] data = new byte[1024];
            while ((nRead = is.read(data, 0, data.length)) != -1) {
              buffer.write(data, 0, nRead);
            }

            try {
                deserialize(data);
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            buffer.flush();

           InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
           s.close();


    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
    }


    }

}
```

// Deseralize the bytes

```
public static Object deserialize(byte[] bytes) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    ByteArrayInputStream b = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
    ObjectInputStream o = new ObjectInputStream(b);
    return o.readObject();
}
```

Please help

Comment: Catch NPE/ makes the function throws NPE also in case you have read nothing

Comment: I tried, but still app closing.

Comment: I can see the data like O4��'�?I'�Q���?���t��?��4]K_�?��c]b��?Y�9y,��?I�8l�L�?-�~kH�?��) how to convert this data to readable formate

Comment: Getting java.io.StreamCorruptedException near ObjectInputStream o = new ObjectInputStream(b);

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11147759/android-tcp-client-read-socket-in-a-textview

Comment: I receive data from server in bytes format, I need to deserialize it to object. BufferedReader.read() will not work here, If I do so will get result as unreadable as I shown in above comment.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11588078/getting-byte-arrays-using-tcp-connections