# How to update the TextView in android using Multithreading in android

Tags: java, android

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements Runnable{
final TextView txtCounter = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.counter);
Thread mythread;
int i = 0;
boolean running = false;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final Button btnstart= (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnStart);
    final Button btnstop = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnStop);
    
    btnstart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            try{
                running = true;
                mythread = new Thread();
                mythread.start();
            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
    
    btnstop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            try{
                running = false;
            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
    
    
}



@Override
public void run(){
    try{
        while(i <= 1234567 && running){
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            i++;
            txtCounter.setText(i);
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  }
```

I am trying to do using two buttons when pressing start button it increments the number every second and updating the TextView till stop button is pressed. In activity_main.xml file only a TextView are there and two Buttons one for start another for stop.

After we press the stop button and if again start is pressed it will start from the last number which was updated last.

But i am getting an error

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.prg4/com.example.prg4.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android Thread modify EditText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7028185/android-thread-modify-edittext)

Comment: You cannot update your UI from any thread other than the Main/UI thread. 
So, just write runOnUIThread { // Set text here } inside your thread.

Comment: Do i need handler to update the TextView

Comment: But its giving the thread error what can i do

Comment: Sorry! I didn't understand you properly. You are actually trying to put texts one by one, aren't you?

Answer (score 0):

My answer may not correct cause, I didn't understand you properly. Maybe, you can get answer from [this splash screen](https://github.com/Istiakshovon/BinaryAndroid/blob/5c2037d52b8a0d11e6566267d2fdf53a3ce7005f/app/src/main/java/com/binary/SplashScreenActivity.java#L91)

```
Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        textView.setText(charSequence.subSequence(0,index++));
        if(index <= charSequence.length()){
            handler.postDelayed(runnable,delay);
        }
    }
};

public void animatText(CharSequence cs){
    charSequence = cs;
    index = 0;
    textView.setText("");
    handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
    handler.postDelayed(runnable,delay);
}
```

I added it to splash screen. A text(Binary) is going to run

Output is like :

> B
> i
> n
> a
> r
> y

One by one every letter is showing. I am not sure it is your answer or not